# d-m-y how to show it right?

Tags: php

```
$datum = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$geboortedatum = $_POST ['geboortedatum'];
$geboortedatum = date ('d/m/Y');**
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$adres = $_POST['adres'];
$postwoon = $_POST['postwoon'];
$bsn = $_POST['bsn'];
$telefoon = $_POST['telefoon'];
$mobiel = $_POST['mobiel'];
$factuuradres = $_POST['factuuradres'];
$opmerkingen = $_POST['opmerkingen'];
```

This is a small code of a contact form (by mail). All the things work, only the `$geboortedatum` (birthday) won't work. Does anyone know how to fix it?

In the emails it shows up like today, but it has to show the birthday.

Comment: Yeah, *"Argh"* 's the word.

Comment: haahah yup rip :(

Comment: now you went an undid a perfectly good edit on someone's part. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40134871/2

Comment: More than 2 words, can you have error reporting in email? xD

Comment: It is not really an error. It shows the day where we living at, not the day that has been put in

Comment: maybe `$geboortedatum = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($geboortedatum));`

Comment: @Willem-Jelle: On line 2 you set a variable to the posted date.  Then immediately afterward, on line 3, you set it to the current date.  So thereafter the value of that variable will be the current date.

Comment: @David Thanks bro! :)

Comment: @devpro hey man thanks for helping, roberts answer helped me the best but thanks for thinking with me :)

Comment: You don't need edit question and add "HAS BEEN FIXED" The question is closed when one of the answers is marked by OP as the one that solved problem.

Comment: I rolled the question back to another revision. Please don't re-edit unless you have anything you really need to add. Seeing that the question's been solved, there is nothing to do to the question. Accepting an answer given that resolved it is enough. If you do re-edit, the question will be flagged and possibly locked by a moderator.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oops, my bad.. Thanks for editting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to pass second argument to date function so change

```
$geboortedatum = date('d/m/Y');
```

to

```
$geboortedatum = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_POST['geboortedatum']));
```

assuming that `geboortedatum` is valid date. When you don't pass second argument to date function it will take 'NOW' so it will output today's date.

Comment: Thanks bro! It worked !!

Comment: If it worked you can mark it as answer. And also you should read how to ask questions here :)

Comment: aah I'll do in future, and I will mark your answer as a working answer! I'm sorry for my way of asking..